# Spacy 3.1 - KeyError: 'train' using spacy train command

Tags: python, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I'm following this tutorial https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart in order to train a custom model of distilbert.
Everything is already installed, data are converted and the config file is ready.

When I launch this training command:

```
 python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy
```

this error occur:

```
2021-08-30 11:43:04.292025: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
ℹ Saving to output directory: output
ℹ Using CPU

=========================== Initializing pipeline ===========================
[2021-08-30 11:43:08,117] [INFO] Set up nlp object from config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 69, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 497, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 60, in train_cli
    nlp = init_nlp(config, use_gpu=use_gpu)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\spacy\training\initialize.py", line 59, in init_nlp
    train_corpus, dev_corpus = resolve_dot_names(config, dot_names)
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow-2.1\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 470, in resolve_dot_names
    if registry.is_promise(config[section]):
KeyError: 'train'
```

I'm on python 3.6 and these are the installed spacy versions:

```
spacy                    3.1.2
spacy-alignments         0.8.3
spacy-legacy             3.0.8
spacy-transformers       1.0.5
```

For completeness, these are config.cfg file and the python code to convert imdb data for spacy (train e dev .spacy files):

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = "pytorch"
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "it"
pipeline = ["transformer","textcat"]
batch_size = 128
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.textcat]
factory = "textcat"
threshold = 0.5

[components.textcat.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatBOW.v2"
exclusive_classes = true
ngram_size = 1
no_output_layer = false
nO = null

[components.transformer]
factory = "transformer"
max_batch_items = 4096
set_extra_annotations = {"@annotation_setters":"spacy-transformers.null_annotation_setter.v1"}

[components.transformer.model]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v1"
name = "distilbert-base-multilingual-cased"

[components.transformer.model.get_spans]
@span_getters = "spacy-transformers.strided_spans.v1"
window = 128
stride = 96

[components.transformer.model.tokenizer_config]
use_fast = true

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
accumulate_gradient = 3
dev_corpus = "dev.spacy"
train_corpus = "train.spacy"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_padded.v1"
discard_oversize = true
size = 2000
buffer = 256
get_length = null

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001

[training.optimizer.learn_rate]
@schedules = "warmup_linear.v1"
warmup_steps = 250
total_steps = 20000
initial_rate = 0.00005

[training.score_weights]
cats_score = 1.0
cats_score_desc = null
cats_micro_p = null
cats_micro_r = null
cats_micro_f = null
cats_macro_p = null
cats_macro_r = null
cats_macro_f = null
cats_macro_auc = null
cats_f_per_type = null
cats_macro_auc_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

The code:

```
import spacy
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from ml_datasets import imdb
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

train_data, valid_data = imdb()

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')


def make_docs(data):
    docs = []
    for doc, label in tqdm(nlp.pipe(data, as_tuples=True), total=len(data)):
        doc.cats['positive'] = label
        docs.append(doc)
    return docs


train_docs = make_docs(train_data)
doc_bin = DocBin(docs=train_docs)
doc_bin.to_disk('./train.spacy')

valid_docs = make_docs(valid_data)
doc_bin = DocBin(docs=valid_docs)
doc_bin.to_disk('./dev.spacy')
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your config is wrong.

```
[training]
accumulate_gradient = 3
dev_corpus = "dev.spacy"
train_corpus = "train.spacy"
```

This is a little confusing, but the `corpus` values here are not file paths, they are the location of the value **in the config**. By default they are `corpora.train` and `corpora.dev`; usually you want to keep them that way. See [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/data-formats#config-training).

This error happens because spaCy looks for the `[train]` block in the config but there's no such thing.

If you change that back it should work.